# Do you add a new noble if one is taken?

Tags: splendor

If you read the rules of splendor, you only get a fixed number of nobles (number of players + 1). But in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFpCWxbm7Lg&t=890s) they add a new noble every time one is taken. Did I misinterpreted the rules or do they use "other" rules in the video?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No you do not; they are playing incorrectly in that video.

From [the rules](https://cdn.1j1ju.com/medias/7f/91/ba-splendor-rulebook.pdf):

> Shuffle the noble tiles and reveal as many of them as there are players plus one (example: 5 tiles for a 4 player game).
> The remaining tiles are removed from the game; **they will not be used during the game.**

Comment: Thanks I already thought that but their video made me wonder.